# Author Channel Name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want it to type the text channel name but it doesn't work please help

```
@client.command()
async def lock(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.discord.text_channel.name
    server = ctx.message.guild
    overwrites_everyone = ctx.message.channel.overwrites_for(server.default_role)
    overwrites_everyone.send_messages = False
    await ctx.message.channel.set_permissions(server.default_role, overwrite=overwrites_everyone)
    await ctx.send(f"{channel} it is closed ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the current text channel by doing ctx.channel

```py
@bot.command
async def channel(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.send('Your are in ' + channel + ' text channel.')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `ctx` (Context) object, you're able to get the channel directly by doing `ctx.channel`. It returns a `TextChannel` object which you're then able to get other attributes from:

```py
@bot.command()
async def whereami(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"You're in a channel called {ctx.channel} ({ctx.channel.mention})!")
```

And as seen in the example, you're able to get the channel's mention by accessing the `.mention` attribute. This is equivalent to `f"<#{ctx.channel.id}>"`

When converting the channel object to a string, it displays the channel's name. It's the equivalent of `ctx.channel.name`.

---

**References:**

- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)
- [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel)
- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`TextChannel.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.mention)